# GEOMETRY triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

MY APPROACH: LET $AB=x$, so $AE=\frac12x$, and we can find $BE$ via trigonometry.

I have $AE$ and $BE$ in terms of $AB$, and the area of triangle $ABE$.

Triangle $BEC$ is common in the quadrilateral $DEBC$ and triangle $ABC$.
So if I can get the smaller triangle formed by orthocenter and $DE$, I think I would get the answer.
it seems to me that data is insufficient  in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: What relation can you see between $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle AED$?

Finding this can give you $S_{AED}$ and then use $S_{DECB}=S_{ABC}-S_{AED}$

Comment: they do not seem similar or congruent...should i construct the pedal triangle to see something ?

Comment: They are similar. What does this tell you about the ratio of areas?

Comment: 3;4 would be the answer in that case...ration of area is square of ratio of sides.....but i can not see how is the line DE parallel to BC?

Comment: It isn't parallel

Comment: i can see that they are similar by calculating angles but that naturally implies that they are parallel as corresponding angles are equal

Comment: That's false, look at the angles again

Comment: <ADE=<B AND <AED=<C?

Comment: they have to be parallel

Comment: No, they don't have to be - this is the main part of the argument so I want you to see why this is true. Your pairs of angles are wrong

Comment: well i got that but i don't think by the right method.. i drew a cyclic quadrilateral and equated angles in the same segment ....do you have a shorter method ?